# How to get DIVS to line up in Bootstrap row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap and am creating a navbar. Here is the HMTL:

```
<div id="root" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
     <a class="nav-link" href="/menus"> Menus </a></div>
   <div class="col-2"><a class="nav-link" href="/meals"> Meals </a> 
      </div>
   <div class="col-2"><a class="nav-link" href="/components"> Components </a></div>
   <div class="col-2"><a class="nav-link" href="/recipes"> Recipes </a></div>
   <div class="col-2"><a class="nav-link" href="/ingredients"> Ingredients </a></div>
</div>
```

Instead of lining up, the DIV's just run down the side of the screen. I know the space is being made in the browser because when I use the element inspector, I can see the 'row' and 'container-fluid' divs are stretching across the screen. I know it must be something stupid small, but I cannot find it.

How can I correct this to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has some great documentation about navbars and other fun stuff: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

---

You probably want something like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/link1">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/link2">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/link3">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Always try checking documentation. You will probably always find a solution to your problems, and at the same time, discover amazing functionalities.